# Styling overflow:scroll scrollbar with css

Tags: css, overflow

Can I design the scrollbar that comes with the overflow:scroll of an element? For example giving it border radius to become rounder?

Comment: Show your code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can style scrollbars to a degree in both webkit browsers and IE, for Firefox no such CSS exists however so you will need to resort to using a Javascript plugin

### Webkit CSS Properties

```
::-webkit-scrollbar  
::-webkit-scrollbar-button  
::-webkit-scrollbar-track  
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece    
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb  
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner  
::-webkit-resizer
```

### Internet Explorer CSS Properties

```
scrollbar-face-color
scrollbar-shadow-color
scrollbar-highlight-color
scrollbar-3dlight-color
scrollbar-darkshadow-color
scrollbar-track-color
scrollbar-arrow-color
```

### Firefox / Other Javascript Libraries

1. [Perfect Scrollbar](http://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/)
2. [Tiny Scrollbar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/)
3. [Control Scrollbar](http://livepipe.net/control/scrollbar)

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so...

Take a look at this tutorial

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-styling-scrollbars-to-match-your-ui-design--webdesign-9430